# Syncfusion Data Grid loading not stopping using FutureBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datagrid, syncfusion, flutter-futurebuilder

I am building an application using Flutter. I have to create a paginated data grid which I am creating using [Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/paging) library where I am loading data from the API. The code that I am using is mostly the same as I have linked. I have attached the snippet where I am
[waiting for the data here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EZVZ.png) When I include the three lines: rows function, nvsPageCount, _nvsDataSource inside the futurebuilder, the data grid data loads infinitely. But when I initialize these in the initState function, it works perfectly but it gives error when the data is not loaded. [Here the datagrid keeps on loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RabHI.png).[The rest of the code for the data grid is attached here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZBLM.png) If you want to see the descriptions of the rest of the code you can check the link for syncfusion that I have attached above. I have searched everywhere for the solution to this but I can't find any. I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind syncfusion products are not open source, but are released under a commercial license which might have financial implications.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)